# Geometries Vs Shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 2d

I am new to 2D design, I am not able to understand what the below statement mean from MSDN Link - [Geometry Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Could you explain what it means and when should I prefer Geometry over Shape and vise versa?

> Because they are elements, Shape objects can render themselves and
>   participate in the layout system, while Geometry objects cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Shape elements, Geometry objects aren’t **UIElement** entities. UIElement objects
have an **intrinsic ability** to render themselves and expose graphical properties, such as
Opacity, that Geometry objects don’t have.UIElement provides a starting point for element layout characteristics, and also exposes virtual methods that derived classes can override, which can influence the layout rendering behavior of the element and its child elements. Why, then, would you consider using a
Geometry? Well, a Geometry allows you to do the following

> 1)Define a geometric shape. For example, imagine creating a user-based rating
>   system. In this scenario, you may want to use a set of five-pointed stars to rate an
>   item. Although a star isn’t a predefined shape, you could create this element
>   using a Geometry.
>
> 2)Define a region for clipping. Clipping is used to limit the visible area of another
>   object.
>
> 3)Define a region that can be used for hit-testing.

A Geometry is an abstract concept. In fact, you can’t deliberately create just
a Geometry. Instead, you must rely on the geometrical concepts spread across three
basic categories: simple, path, and composite geometries.